# Is it possible to call a class method from within itself in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, class, recursion, methods

I was wondering if there is a way to call a class method from within itself, when defining it, the same way a function can call itself from within itself, in order to achieve recursion. I could not find the answer to it anywhere, unfortunately.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Yes. A method is just a function. What, exactly, isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the class method -

```py
class Foo:
  def stairs (n = 0):
    if n <= 0:
      return ""
    else:
      return Foo.stairs(n - 1) + ("#" * n) + "\n"

print(Foo.stairs(3))
#
##
###

print(Foo.stairs(5))
#
##
###
####
#####
```

Or call the instance method -

```py
class Foo:
  def stairs (self, n = 0):
    if n <= 0:
      return ""
    else:
      return self.stairs(n - 1) + ("#" * n) + "\n"

f = Foo()

print(f.stairs(3))
#
##
###

print(f.stairs(5))
#
##
###
####
#####
```